# node-usb throwing a LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS error

Tags: javascript, error-handling, electron, node-usb

Im making an app that uses node-usb and electron. For some reason Im getting a LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS when I try to transfer data. I wrote a small function that should return the output endpoint but it errors when I claim the device. This is the code that Im working with. Im on a Mac but it happens on Windows.

```
  const transferNextItem = () => {
    if (device) {
        const outEndpoint = getUsbOutEndpoint(device)
        const transferData = ['0x01','0x0C', '0xC0']
        outEndpoint.transfer(transferData, err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('transferNextItem err', err);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

```
export const getUsbOutEndpoint = (device) => {
    if (device) {
        device.open();
        const iFace = device.interface(0)
        if (iFace.isKernelDriverActive()) {
            iFace.detachKernelDriver();
        }
        iFace.claim(); // This is where it throws the error.
        const outEndpoint = iFace.endpoints[1]
        return outEndpoint
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

I searched online. I was trying to find a solution to the error but with no luck.